# WPF: Не обнаруживается имя пользовательского класса в пространстве имён local

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Я создал C#-класс `CustomControl` в корне проекта, удаследовав его от уже существующего элемента. Как в файле разметки XAML, так и в словаре, где объявлены стили, мне Visual Studio пишет, что "Имя `CustomControl` отсутствует в пространстве имён `clr-namesspace:MyProject`" (`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"`). В чём может быть причина?

Начало объявления класса:

```
namespace MyProject {
    class CustomControl : ToggleButton {
```

Попытка определить стиль:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
```

Comment: Вот именно так: `clr-namespace:namesspace:MyProject`?

Comment: Если что, надо просто `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"`, может в этом дело?

Comment: @ VladD, конечно нет, ошибка copy-paste. Исправил.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu: А попробуйте убрать всё из разметки, скомпилировать без ошибок (!), и потом вернуть разметку назад.

Comment: @VladD, Ну если убрать всё из разметки, будет ошибка  `error MC3000: route not found. XML is unavailable`.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu: Ну да, это я погорячился. Уберите всё _внутри_ корневого элемента (Grid или что у вас там).

Comment: @VladD, я не знаю почему, но это... сработало! Вы можете объяснить, что произошло?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu: Ага, знаю эту магию. Тут где-то уже было похожий вопрос, сейчас найду дубликат.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu: Нашёл дубликат.